# Finding the probability density function and the distribute accumulate function

Tags: statistics, proof-verification

For a random variable $X$, $(X^3-1)$ is uniformly distributed in the interval $[0,7]$

> I need to find the probability density function and the cumulative distribution function of $X$

My attempt:

$(X^3-1)=7\Longrightarrow X=\color{blue}2$

cumulative distribution function:

$$F_{X}(x)=
\begin{cases}
0&&;x<2\\
\frac{x^3-1}{7}&&;0\leq x \leq 2\\
1&&;x>2\\
\end{cases}$$

probability density function

$$F'_{X}(x)=f_{X}(x)=
\begin{cases}
0&&;x<2\\
\frac{3x^2}{7}&&;0\leq x \leq 2\\
0&&;x>2\\
\end{cases}$$

> Is it correct?

Comment: There are many notational errors involving switching the roles of $X$ and $x$. There are also some incorrect intervals. Substantial rewriting is needed.

Comment: ..I will edit..

Comment: For the cdf (cumulative distribution function) $F_X(x)$, it is $0$ if $x\lt 1$, and $\frac{x^3-1}{7}$ for $1\le x\lt 2$.

Comment: .and  if  $x>2$.?

Comment: You had that part right, so I did not comment on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cumulative distribution function:
$$F_{X}(x)=
\begin{cases}
0&;x < 1\\
\frac{x^3-1}{7}&;1\leq x \leq 2\\
1&;x>2\\
\end{cases}$$

probability density function:

$$f_{X}(t)=
\begin{cases}
0&;t \not\in (1,2)\\
\frac{x^2}{7}&; t \in (1,2)\\
\end{cases}$$