# Finding the expected value and variance of ${X^3}$

Tags: statistics, proof-verification

For a random variable $X$, $(X^3-1)$ is uniformly distributed in the interval $[0,7]$

> I need to find the expected value and variance of $\color{blue}{X^3}$

and I know that:

cumulative distribution function:
$$F_{X}(x)=
\begin{cases}
0&;x < 1\\
\frac{x^3-1}{7}&;1\leq x \leq 2\\
1&;x>2\\
\end{cases}$$

probability density function:

$$f_{X}(t)=
\begin{cases}
0&;t \not\in (1,2)\\
\frac{3x^2}{7}&; t \in (1,2)\\
\end{cases}$$

> My attempt:

$X^3-1 \sim U(0,7)$

$X^3 \sim U(1,8)$

$E(X^3)=\frac{1+8}{2}=4.5$

$\text{Var}(X^3)=\frac{(b-a)^2}{12}=\frac{(8-1)^2}{12}\approx4.083$

> Is it correct?

Comment: At the end, are you aiming for $E[X]$ or $E[X^3]$ and similarly with the variance?

Comment: I edited, like this?

Comment: So why bother with the distribution functions for $X$?

Comment: Your solution is correct, but finding the c.d.f. of $X$ doesn't help. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Apparently that was another question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383106/finding-the-probability-density-function-and-the-distribute-accumulate-function

Comment: @Henry This is from the previous section of the question

Comment: The beginning, about the distribution of $X$, is not needed,  though one could use it. But I think you don't. Clearly $Y=X^3$ is uniform on $[1,8]$, and now the mean of $Y$ is obvious by symmetry. The variance can be found by quoting a standard formula, as I think you do, or by first calculating $E(Y^2)=\int_1^8 \frac{y^2}{7}\,dy$. Your answer for the variance is right.

Comment: Another part is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383320/finding-the-expected-value-and-variance-of-x